# Saving csv in specific json format

Tags: python, json

How do i save my csv into json  , where column ="questions"
Particularly in this format

```
[
    "What is dewa?" , "what is regulations?" ,"What is the fire rating for building having more than 2 basements?"
]
```

Right now I am getting my json is in this format

```
{"Question":{"0":"what is dewa?","1":"what is regulations?","2":"What is the fire rating for building having more than 2 basements?"}}
```

Code , for csv too json

```
import pandas as pd
read_csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\heba.fatima\Desktop\final-fire/answers.csv')  # or delimiter = ';'

read_csv=read_csv[["Question"]]
read_csv.head()
read_csv.to_json (r'C:\Users\heba.fatima\Desktop\flaskapi\data\answers.json')
```

Comment: And what exactly is preventing you from changing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orient` argument for `to_json`:

```
read_csv['Question'].to_json(orient='values')
```

output:

```
["what is dewa?", "what is regulations?", "What is the fire rating for building having more than 2 basements?"]
```